# How to remove WWW prefix, add https and rewrite for codeigniter mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm having headache trying to setup a virtualhost in Apache to work with codeigniter.

I'd like to : 
- Remove www (if present) 
- Redirect to https 
- Rewrite the request header to redirect to codeigniter parsing

Here's my code so far:

```
           RewriteEngine on
           RewriteBase /
           RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
           RewriteRule (.*) https://abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
           RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.com/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it simply doesn't work; what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just noob-proofing the question; do you definitely have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: of course;) noob-proofed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the three separate sections and do them one at a time, do you find only one that doesn't work?

***Force https***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

First, check if "off" is correct for your installation. You may have better luck checking on the Port number your server uses for https

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://abc.com/$1 [L]
```

***Force abc.com rather than www.abc.com***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Since you already hard code your domain name in this .htaccess, you might use it in the RewriteRule here rather than %1. Now, if you're converting to https above, is this going to send you back to http, regardless of whether you were already in https? I would also use . instead of ^, and do you really want to lose the rest of the URL?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.com/$1 [L]
```

***Bogus file or directory, flip to a fixed URI***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.com/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will append any existing Query String to the q=original path/file. Without it, I think the q=original would be lacking the old Query String.

Note that all of these should produce a 302 code (equal to [R=302]). If you want a 301, you'll have to explicitly give it ([R=301,L]). I'm not sure under what circumstances multiple R=301s in an .htaccess will give an error, so you may have to experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?(.+)  [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1     [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://abc.com/index.php?q=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```